# Переменные в HQL Hive

Tags: sql, hql, hive

Добрый день коллеги. Не могу понять причину, почему не результаты не записываются в переменную, из за чего не выполняется основной хайв запрос. Предпологаю что хайв не понимает, что переменным я присваиваю результирующие данные первого запроса. Как в таком случае быть, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
select * from field f 
full join periods p on 1=1 
full join result r on r.block=f.block and r.field=f.field_name  and p.period=r.period
where r.block is null 
order by f.block, f.field_name, p.period 
 limit 1; 

set bl=f.block; 
 set bl; 

set fl=f.field_name; 
 set fl; 

set pr=p.period; 
 set pr; 

set d1=p.day1; 
 set d1; 

set d2=p.day2; 
 set d2; 

-- insert into result 
select ${hiveconf:bl}, ${hiveconf:fl}, ${hiveconf:pr}, min(day), max(day) 
from l_hdb_det.wsrm_log 
where day between ${hiveconf:d1} and ${hiveconf:d2} 
and (${hiveconf:fl} is not null);
```